# CiviCRM on Debian 10 gives warning about PHP MySQL Driver (libmysqlclient)

Tags: php, mysql, webserver, system-status

Recently moved my CiviCRM install to a server running Debain 10 which brings:

- php7.3
- MariaDB 10.3.17

Everything seems to be working fine, except that in the system checks I'm now seeing this error/warning:

> **PHP MySQL Driver (libmysqlclient)**
>
> It is recommended, though not yet required, to upgrade your PHP MySQL driver (libmysqlclient) to >= 5.5.3 for utf8mb4 support.

The check seems to get its info from [mysqli_get_client_info](https://www.php.net/mysqli_get_client_info) which on my server emits the following:

```
mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23
```

This is surprising - 5.0?! What to do?

Comment: This came up in labs a few months ago but was resolved (https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1136). But I don't have any insight as to what's different here. Is there anything in that ticket that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Dermerit, the answer seems to be to upgrade!

This code change:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14864/files

Seems to have removed the erroneous warning.